# Помогите с .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

А именно, мне необходимо сделать редиректы для страниц следующим образом.
Все посты расположенные на:

http://domen.ru/cat1/post-name

перенаправить на :

http://domen.ru/cat2/post-name

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь должен быть вариант написания который вам подойдет [редирект](http://kuratov.ru/blog/entry/301-redirekt-.htaccess-nekotorye-nyuansy/)

---

**добавлено из комментариев**

Вот так заработало

```
Redirect 301 /cat1 domen.ru/cat2
```

Comment: Ошибка 500. Внутренняя ошибка сервера

Возможные причины ошибки: неподдерживаемые директивы или синтаксическая ошибка в файле .htaccess, ошибка в CGI-скрипте или неверные права.

Вот это сообщает сервер

Comment: Перписал в одну строку.. Серверная ошибка пропала, но редирект не работает

Comment: Redirect 301 /cat1 http://domen.ru/cat2/ вот так заработало.

Comment: Ну и здорово))